# Displaying closed cases in the dashboard

Tags: civicase

I'm using compucorp's fork of civiCase. Nice!
Currently in the case manager page, only active cases are displayed (as confirmed by the "Satus: All open cases" placeholder). I'm trying to display by default both active and closed cases.. But I can not find a toggle to do so, any advice?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to support a "showCasesFromAllStatuses" parameter on that page but I have no idea how to set it.

It looks like they removed the mechanism for it in https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicase/pull/825, but left some of the code behind.

As a workaround you can comment out this line, but the text in the dropdown will still default to "All Open Cases", but the table will be showing all statuses. https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicase/blob/f815d9886bb8d34d8584b8245339e2cb0b9f3d80/ang/civicase/case/list/directives/case-list-table.directive.js#L383